# Inserting pirmary key for Table with auto-increment

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to find a way to perform an insert on a slick `Table` whose primary key is an auto-increment but force the primary key to the value in the mapped case class. I.e. given:

```
case class Foo(id: Int, name: String)

class FooTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Foo](tag, "foo") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def name = column[String]("name")

  def * = (id, name) <> (Foo.tupled, Foo.unapply)
}

val foos = TableQuery[FooTable]
```

If I do a regular insert via

```
db.run(foos += Foo(123,"bar"))
```

it will set `id` to whatever the next *auto-increment* value is, rather than setting it to 123. Is there a syntax for forcing `id` to be set to the value in the provided case class `Foo`?

Comment: What would you like to happen in case of id clashing?

Comment: @mfirry This code is for loading initial data during a test. I have no plans to use this feature in production code for precisely your specified reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout `forceInsert`

> Inserts can be a bit surprising at first […] Columns that are
>   auto-incremented are automatically ignored, so inserting into them has
>   no effect. Using forceInsert allows actual insertion into
>   auto-incremented columns.

Source : [Coming from SQL to Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/sql-to-slick.html#slick-12)